# starting glassfish on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: installation, startup, glassfish

I have installed glassfish in ubuntu 12.04 from below: (the first one)

http://glassfish.java.net/public/downloadsindex.html#top

I have user-admin and password-admin for administrator and installation directory is root/glassfish

After installing it started the deafult domain automatically so I see the admin login page when I type "http://localhost:4848/" in the browser. I am able to login also with above user and password.

In the quick-start guide it says following to start the server

```
as-install/bin/asadmin start-domain
```

to stop:

`as-install/bin/asadmin stop-domain`

I tried to start and stop to glassfish like that.

1) I moved to usr/local/glassfish3.1.2.2/bin directory and then I type folllowing:

`asadmin start-domain` but it gives me following:

```
No command 'asadmin' found, did you mean:
 Command 'amadmin' from package 'amanda-server' (universe)
asadmin: command not found
```

I get same when I try to stop it by `as-admin stop-domain`

**May be I have misunderstood the instructions to start and stop the server.

Could someone please tell me what am I doing wrong here ?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The directory is not on your ***PATH*** variable. Use `./asadmin` or asadmin with full path:

```
/usr/local/glassfish3.1.2.2/bin/asadmin start-domain
/usr/local/glassfish3.1.2.2/bin/asadmin stop-domain
```

or add the path to your ***PATH*** variable

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/glassfish3.1.2.2/bin
asadmin start-domain
asadmin stop-domain
```

To make it permanent, add the ***PATH*** modification to your `.profile` or `/etc/profile`.

Comment: Thanks. With ./asadmin I am able to run start and stop command. But when I run stop command, it shows "command stop executed successfully" So I think it stopped properly but even after stopping when I type "http://localhost:4848/" in browser, it shows me login page. why does it show even if I stopped it ?

Comment: Try running `lsof -i :4848` to see what is running on that port. Maybe it is a previous instance that you did not manage to kill properly?

Comment: thanks again..U were right, it was already running when I killed that process, the command seem to work fine.

Comment: hmm, where does current version install asadmin to?